# How to capture a property changed even of one view model in another view model

Tags: wpf, mvvm, notify

i have view model class A and it has the property "a".

and i have class called B , and it ha sproperty "b" where i store list of all A[] as list.

if any change in the property a , i would like to change the property in the parent class A.

that is

class B
{

property b1;

List A[]

}

Class A
{

property a1;

}

I am using MVVM and notify property chnaged event is there in both the places. what i dont know how to wire up both .

Comment: did you mean if there is change in property 'a' of any instance of class A you need notification in Class B?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my `BaseCollection` class which extends `ObservableCollection<T>`, I have a created a `CollectionItemPropertyChanged` `delegate` that I can attach a handler to, so I can be notified when property values have changed in *any* item in the collection:

```
public delegate void ItemPropertyChanged(T item, string propertyName);
```

Then I add a getter and setter of the type of the `delegate`:

```
public virtual ItemPropertyChanged CurrentItemPropertyChanged { get; set; }
```

To achieve this, I have to attach a handler to each item's `PropertyChanged` event:

```
public BaseCollection(IEnumerable<T> collection)
{
    foreach (T item in collection) Add(item);
}

public new void Add(T item)
{
    item.PropertyChanged += Item_PropertyChanged;
    base.Add(item);
}
```

I also need to remove the handlers when objects are removed:

```
public new bool Remove(T item)
{
    if (item == null) return false;
    item.PropertyChanged -= Item_PropertyChanged;
    return base.Remove(item);
}
```

Then there is the `Item_PropertyChanged` handler:

```
private void Item_PropertyChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
    if (CollectionItemPropertyChanged != null) CollectionItemPropertyChanged(
currentItem, e.PropertyName);
}
```

This can then be used in your class `B` like so:

```
public List<A> Items
{
    get { return items; }
    set 
    {
        items = value; 
        items.CollectionItemPropertyChanged += YourHandler;
        NotifyPropertyChanged(Items);
    }
}
```

Then your handler:

```
private void YourHandler(A item, string propertyName)
{
    // propertyName is the name of the changed property from the A object named item
}
```

To answer your question more directly, you can attach a handler from one view model to this `delegate` in another... for example:

```
Items.CollectionItemPropertyChanged += ViewModel2.YourHandler;
```

Or from the other view model:

```
ViewModel1.Items.CollectionItemPropertyChanged += YourHandler;
```

Answer (score -1):

Create View Model A as Singleton and update the a property using that instance.